# CSS background-image to access multiple images

Tags: html, jquery, css, foreach, background-image

I am creating a div within a forEach loop to hold images (every image has its own div). The images are held in a separate folder 'media'. By setting the url of background-image in the way I have in the code below, I can access a single image, so all divs are populated with the same image.

Is there a way to populate each created div with a separate image, via the url? There are the same number of created divs as there are images in the media file.

```
    $('.my-media').html('');
    media.forEach(function (mediaItem) {
      var div = $('<div>');
      $(div).addClass("class-a");
      $(div).addClass("class-b");
      $(div).css('background-image', 'url(media/0.jpg)');
      $(".my-media").append(div)
    });
  }
```

**Update - I have changed the code to this:

````
    $('.my-media').html('');
    media.forEach(function (mediaItem) {
      var div = $('<div>');
      $(div).addClass("class-a");
      $(div).addClass("class-b");
      for (let i=0; i < mediaItemIndex.length; i++){
        $(div).css('background-image', `url('media/${mediaItemIndex[i]}.jpg')`); 
      }

      $(".my-media").append(div)
    });
  } 

where 
``` var mediaItemIndex = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
````

but this is now only displaying the final image for all the divs. Again, any and all help/ suggestions would be appreciated.

FINAL UPDATE: I've solved the issue.
The path file to the images was stored in an array of objects under 'media_url'. By using `.replace("../","")`, I got rid of the unnecessary part of the file path and could access the images.

The way I was initially trying to access the images was failing as it was creating a loop within a loop. The forEach loop was looping through the images already, so when I used `for(let i =0;...` I was creating an infinite loop that only displayed the final image.

Replacing this line `$(div).css('background-image', 'url(media/0.jpg)');`
with this line from my first edit
`` $(div).css('background-image', `url(${mediaItem.media_url.replace("../","")})`); ``

means that every image only displays once - i.e. problem solved.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Comment: How is the JS to know what the URLs of the images should be? Is that what the `mediaItem` value contains?

Comment: Are you asking for JS to be able to read a file directory, or do you know that the files are called 0.jpg, 1.jpg all the way to n.jpg where n+1 is the number of divs already created or are the divs to be created?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In all honesty, I don't know. This is a snippet of a main.js file that I have to rebuild as part of a project working with an API. I am a real newbie so please excuse my poor jargon. mediaItem is passed as a function argument in other places, but never defined. Based on how it is used elsewhere, it seems to be that it is referring to the individual image files, but again, that isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @AHaworth The files are named chronologically from 0.jpg up to 24.jpg. The divs are created within the same function that sets the url path. Again, apologies if my jargon isn't great, I'm very new to this

Comment: Where is media defined? And what HTML do you start with?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, here it is.

```
$('.my-media').html('');
media.forEach(function (mediaItem, mediaItemIndex) {
  var div = $('<div>');
  $(div).addClass("class-a");
  $(div).addClass("class-b");
  $(div).css('background-image', `url(media/${mediaItemIndex}.jpg)`);
  $(".my-media").append(div)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried to implement this, but I'm struggling. From my understanding, I must write another function that iterates through a list of image file names and assigns an index value, which I can then assign to mediaItemIndex. as the image files are in a separate folder, I understand that I must also include the file path somewhere, but I cannot workout how to connect these pieces. I'd greatly appreciate your advice once again!